# Bootstrap method resampling in matlab

Tags: matlab, time, series, statistics-bootstrap

I am producing a script for creating bootstrap samples (random) from precipitations data set (sskt and kendall tau package in Matlab).

I have one double array with 3 colums from my data.

first is year, second a vector (for season or period) and third the precipitation of this station(vector is the number of the station, i run this method for regional trend).

1970   1   234
1971   1   244
1972   1   344
...   ... ...
1970   2   342
1971   2   356
...   ... ...

etc....i have a 36 years for each of my stations(12 stations=12x36=432data at 3 columns)

i want one m script file that i can call function sskt for N=5000repetitions of my data. My data is a csv file, actually a double matric in matlab. I want a bootstrap method of each column that generates 5000repetitions or 1000. 1000repetitions it means 1000x36=36000repetitions. When first loop of 1000 gives me results...in this loop i called function sskt and as results i have 1000 S slopes, 1000 kendall tau, 1000 sign.
Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Matlab has a bootstrap function for called [bootstrp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/bootstrp.html).  It draws `N` bootstrap data samples, computes statistics on each sample, and returns the results.